# Does gaming on an SSD shorten its lifespan?

Tags: ssd, lifespan

I'm currently downloading GTA V from Steam to my SSD and it will take up about 80GB of space.

My SSD's capacity is 240GB, but after the download it will be left with a small amount of free space of about 30GB.

Does this reduce its lifespan ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How much slower do SSDs get as they fill up or age?](https://superuser.com/questions/1344650/how-much-slower-do-ssds-get-as-they-fill-up-or-age)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, any 'normal' use won't strain a SSD into an early grave, however, having a low amount of free space can cause SSDs to run slower.

It seems the general rule is to only fill a SSD to 85-90%.