# How to properly clone a slightly damaged SSD onto a new one

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, clone, luks

So recently my old SSD (containing /root + /home partitions for my system) broke (details [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1346210/how-toast-is-my-ssd-and-why)) and I went to get a new one. Now I wanted to clone it but ran into the following issues:

```
$ pv /dev/sdd > /dev/sda
4.24GiB 0:00:18 [ 234MiB/s] [==>                          ]  7% ETA 0:03:55
pv: /dev/sdd: read failed: Input/output error

$ dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/sda bs=1M status=progress
dd: error reading '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
4397+1 records in
4397+1 records out
4611493888 bytes (4.6 GB, 4.3 GiB) copied, 22.0249 s, 209 MB/s
```

The old SSD still kinda works. There are lots of system freezes due to it being damaged but I can unlock, mount and use it quite fine still. I can access all data (AFAIK) and a full backup using `tar` worked well too.

The reasons I would greatly prefer a direct clone over file-by-file (or `tar`) copying is:

1. Convenience
2. Speed
3. Rather complex encryption on the disk, that I'd rather not re-setup again

[This website](https://elinux.org/Transfer_system_disk_from_SD_card_to_hard_disk) suggests using `conv=noerror` with `dd`, but I'm unsure whether this is safe or not. I have the same concerns about `dd_rescue` and clonezilla's `-rescue`.

**Question**: How can I safely clone my old SSD onto the new one, and is a `md5sum` check afterwards sufficient to make sure the clone was 100% successful?

The website I've linked above suggests using gparted to check if the clone was successful, but AFAIK gparted doesn't work with LUKS encrypted partitions. (To make things more complicated: The LUKS header is detached.)

**Bonus question**: My drive's decryption is done at boot, using grub and the partitions's ID (not UUID). Is it enough for me to update the ID in my crypttab and grub's config or do I need to do more?

---

**Edit**: I just realized that `md5sum` will most likely fail to read the drive aswell. Is there any other way to safely tell if the clone was successful?

---

**UPDATE:** So I've tried clonezilla with the `-rescue` option. It *seemed* to work and I can unlock the LUKS container to reveal the LVM but when I try to mount the root partition I get the following:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/vvg-root /mnt/sda
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vvg-root,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Relevant data from `dmesg`:

```
[ 4686.401702] JBD2: no valid journal superblock found
[ 4686.401707] EXT4-fs (dm-3): error loading journal
```

So I guess that didn't work as planned. Has anyone a better idea, please?

---

**UPDATE2:** I ran a `fsck.ext4 -yv` on the new drive's partition. I was flooded with errors. In the millions. Now I'm able to mount it, but pretty much all of my files are missing. The /home directory, among many others, is gone entirely. There should be around 30-35GB of data on it. Now it's 53MB.

Is my only option really to rollback the `tar` backup I have? I'm thinking maybe a one-on-one rsync copy is better, since that would report if a specific file is damaged/unreadable, right? I used `--verify` when I made the `tar` archive though and it didn't report any errors.

Comment: [Clonezilla](https://www.clonezilla.org/) with turned `-rescue` option in the "Expert" mode.

Comment: @Alex What exactly does that do? I'd assume it just works like `dd_rescue`, by simply ignoring/skipping IO errors? That scares me off a bit, I'd greatly appreciate an elaboration on how this works and how safe it is to use.

Comment: Yes, clonezilla trying to read multiple times broken sectors and if it failed then it go further to copy rest of content in the same way as `dd_rescue` doing it. I would try first to make an image with clonezilla to be make sure that at least existing data saved then try to "cure" ssd with low level tool such as mhdd or victoria in attempt to force internal ssd controller to replace broken sectors. Low level tool work good on mechanical drives but rarely helpful on ssd drives.

Comment: @Alex I'm going to create an image using `dd_rescue` and then look into those tools.

Comment: Be careful with `dd_rescue`, it trying very hard to read broken part of the disk that may trigger even more damage to SSD (when internal firmware trying to replace broken sectors with healthy ones but there no left spare cells).

Comment: @Alex Wouldn't clonezilla's `-rescue` do the same though?

Comment: Not as hard as `dd_rescue` do that (read forcibly multiple times), clonezilla simply skipping bad sectors and `-rescue` option is a simple flag to not fail and stop on errors but continue coping rest of content instead.

Comment: @Alex I've added an update to my question. After `-rescue`'d CloneZilla copy I'm unable to mount the partition.

Comment: The biggest problem in your case it is LUKS encryption. IMHO the only way to recover data now, - is to force SSD to remap broken sectors (tools: Victoria, MHDD, HDD Regenerator) or find some1 who has PC-3000 hardware tool. How many relocations reported by  S.M.A.R.T in attribute #5? If this value has few remaps then there's  still a chance to recover it.

Comment: @Alex smart values for #5 are: `VALUE: 099, WORST: 099, THRESH: 010, RAW_VALUE: 53248` - Keep in mind that I don't have a real need to recovery data. I have a full `tar` backup that seems to be fine (used `--verify` to test it). I think at this point the easiest way would be to create the new SSD from scratch (encryption and LVM) and then mount the old SSD (which still works) and copy the data from it onto the new one using rsync. I'm downloading hiren's boot CD right now though to give that a try.

Comment: I think that with such huge `RAW_VALUE: 53248` this SSD is a dead horse but you can try. Make sure to complete at least two full scans that finished with zero remaps and make clone ASAP if you would succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>After doing what I stated in my question, I ended up doing the following:

1) Remove the LVM on the new SSD after the failed CloneZilla copy.

2) I kept the outer dm-crypt untouched, since it worked well.

3) I re-created a new LVM and resized everything to fit the new (bigger) SSD.</sup>
<sup><sup>(This is only relevant to my case, hence the smaller font, see question updates)</sup></sup>

## Now for the cloning:

1) I mounted both SSDs' root partitions normally in a live system after unlocking them:

```
# unlock the LUKS containers with cryptsetup first
mount /dev/mapper/ovvg-root /mnt/oldssd
mount /dev/mapper/vvg-root /mnt/newssd
```

2) I used rsync to clone the files:

```
rsync -ahv --progress /mnt/oldssd /mnt/newssd
```

3) Confirmed that the size of all folders match:

```
du -cs /mnt/oldsdd/* && echo " " && du -cs /mnt/newssd/*
```

4) Confirmed that all the files are there, to double-check:

```
find /mnt/oldssd | cut -d "/" - f 4- | sort > oldssd.txt
find /mnt/newssd | cut -d "/" - f 4- | sort > newssd.txt
diff oldssd.txt newssd.txt
```

Eight files weren't present in `newssd.txt` so I assume those had read errors. I ended up leaving those files alone as I have backups, I will copy them manually later.

5) Satisfied my paranoia further by checking on checksums:

```
cd /mnt/oldssd && find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort > /root/oldssd_md5.txt
cd /mnt/newssd && find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort > /root/newssd_md5.txt
cd /root && diff oldssd_md5.txt newssd_md5.txt
```

No output at all - Meaning every file is the same!

**As for the bonus question:**

1) Change device path (using UUID) in `/etc/fstab`
2) Change device path (using `by-id`) in `/etc/default/grub`
3) Since I can't chroot into my system right now I modified the `grub.cfg` directly to reflect the change of the disk's `by-id` - However the better practice is to not do this and instead chroot into the root system and re-configure the GRUB bootloader. I immediately did this after being booted into the system from the new SSD.

More complicated than I wish it would've been, but at least it worked, safely.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd recommend to not use the SSD or run tests on it because it could cause the drive to continue failing, I once had a drive that I was repairing and after running some integrity checks on it, it wouldn't let itself be read at all. If you are still able to see it from a separate system, then it should still be saveable, though usage can cause the chips to stop reading, so I'd try a full clone before doing anything else.
I recommend using Clonezilla from USB as to keep the SSD away from unneeded read/writes during cloning. when you've cloned it, md5sum would the best way to confirm it's all there, although it may not be reliable if it's failing.
A bonus to using a cloning OS or hardware cloner is that all the data is copied sector by sector.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question. I'm not using the SSD anymore and I agree on your points, however a "full clone" *is* what I'm trying. AFAIK does clonezilla's `clonepart` not work with full disks (correct me if I'm wrong please), and clonezilla's `dd` is essentially the same as using `dd` from another system. By the way: I'm trying all of this on a live manjaro system, with the SSD being unmounted and locked. Also, using `pv` or `dd`, a copy is done sector-by-sector too. A "cloning OS" does not much more than use regular UNIX tools.

Comment: @confetti Clonezilla can do full disk cloning when you choose `disk-to-image` or `disk-to-disk` option

Comment: @Alex I'm asking about the underlying tool clonezilla uses to do the cloning. I haven't used clonezilla in a while, but I remember the last time I used it to clone a disk it was using `dd`.

Comment: NO, clonezilla using `dd` only if you asked it about this.

Comment: @confetti It used underlying tool in this order:  `partclone` (default), `partimage` (optional), `ntfsclone` (optional), or `dd` as last resort when it cant figure out filesystems

Comment: @Alex That's what I was thinking, however AFAIK `partclone` and `partimage` are both only available when working with partitions, not full disks. `ntfsclone` is not an option either since it's not NTFS, so in my case it would end up using `dd`. I'm downloading clonezilla right now to see, but I'm pretty sure that's how it was the last time I tried it.

Comment: @confetti Clonezilla isn't just LiveCD that simply running `partclone`, if you do full `disk-to-image/disk` cloning it will recreate the whole disk structure including MBR/GPT as well it will include all partitions that present on a disk.

Comment: @Alex So I just tried it and yes, `dd` is what's being used by clonezilla for disk-to-disk operations. I used `-rescue` and it finished. What should my next step be?

Comment: @confetti It strange that clonezilla used `dd`, usually it fall back to this method only when it can't figure out filesystem. I have great experience with Victoria to force firmware to replace broken sectors. The only thing, it require IDE mode in BIOS. It won't work on AHCI. In advanced or classic remap scanning mode it will force internal controller to replace bad cells from spare ones.

Comment: @Alex I've looked into that tool, but apparently it only runs on Windows. Is there any Linux alternative? I've heard that writing to a bad block will force the disk to re-map it, but overwriting data is not really what I'm after... Also: Well, it might very well be that clonezilla couldn't figure out the filesystem as it's a masked (detached header) LUKS encrypted drive.

Comment: @confetti If it LUKS drive then it explains why `dd` used. As about Victoria, no, - windows version isn't what I mentioned, you need to find Hiren boot CD, there is DOS version (that works in real mode), use Russian version as it is most recent (there a few words that need to be translated, everything else in English). Use `P` to choose SATA channel, then F4 to scan with "classic remap". Vicroria doesn't overwrite broken sectors, it trying first to extract data to RAM then doing multiple writes to bad sector to enforce remap, then restore sector in the same place. Use IDE in BIOS with Victoria